# Error: File not found with singular glob при запуске таска JS в Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Собираю gulp-сборку по уроку из Youtube.
На создании таска JS я встрял.
Сам таск написал, отслеживание js файлов повесил, в сборку включил.

Собственно сам gulpfile.js

```
let project_folder='dist';
let source_folder='src';

let path = {

  build: {
    html: project_folder + '/',
    css: project_folder + '/css/',
    js: project_folder + '/js/',
    img: project_folder + '/img/',
    fonts: project_folder + '/fonts/'
  },

  src: {
    html: [source_folder + '/*.html', '!' + source_folder + '/_*.html'],
    css: source_folder + '/scss/style.scss',
    js: source_folder + '/js/sctipt.js',
    img: source_folder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,icon,webp}',
    fonts: source_folder + '/fonts/'
  },

  watch: {
    html: source_folder + '/**/*.html',
    css: source_folder + '/scss/**/*.scss',
    js: source_folder + '/js/**/*.js',
    img: source_folder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,icon,webp}'
  },

  clean: './' + project_folder + '/',
}

let {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
  fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
  del = require('del'),
  scss = require('gulp-sass'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
  clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename');

function browserSync(params) {
  browsersync.init({
    server:{
      baseDir: './' + project_folder + '/'
    },
    port: 3000,
    notify: false
  })
}

function html() {
  return src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(fileinclude())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function js() {
  return src(path.src.js)
    .pipe(fileinclude())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function css() {
  return src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(
      scss({
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
      })
    )
    .pipe(group_media())
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 5 version'],
        cascade: true
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(clean_css())
    .pipe(
      rename({
        extname: '.min.css'
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function watchFiles(params) {
  gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
  gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
  gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
}

function clean(params) {
  return del(path.clean)
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(html, js, css));
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Полный текс ошики в терминале

```
[sh4rov@keksys gulp-scss-boilerplate]$ gulp js
[23:44:03] Using gulpfile ~/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/gulpfile.js
[23:44:03] Starting 'js'...
[23:44:03] 'js' errored after 16 ms
[23:44:03] Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/src/js/sctipt.js (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob-stream/readable.js:84:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Glob.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at Glob._finish (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)
    at done (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)
    at Glob._processSimple2 (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:688:12)
    at /home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:676:10
    at Glob._stat2 (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:772:12)
    at lstatcb_ (/home/sh4rov/front/gulp-scss-boilerplate/node_modules/glob/glob.js:764:12)
```

Comment: Оказыается проблема была в строчке js: source_folder + '/js/sctipt.js',
sctipt а не script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в строчке js: source_folder + '/js/sctipt.js', пишу sctipt а не script.